# What are the ways to deal with unix fifos using libuv?

Tags: linux, named-pipes, libuv, mkfifo

I have an application that for some complex reasons can communicate only using unix fifos (the ones created via `mkfifo`)

Generally, I deal with it like an ordinary file, but if possible, I would like to be able to use it in an asynchronous way.

I'm already using libuv for other tasks in this same application, so I was wondering how libuv would deal with fifos ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the uv_fs_* APIs, but note that they are really blocking operations running in a threadpool, which by default has a size of 4, so make sure you raise it or don't queue up too many operations or you could stall it. See: http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/threadpool.html#threadpool